# Variable losing value due to scope in bash

Tags: bash

My bash version is **GNU bash, version 4.3.42(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)**. This is a simplified version of my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
touch a.ecl
touch b.ecl

function_syntaxCheckFileName()
{
  return 1 # 1 syntax error
}

tmpTotalErrors=0
result=0
echo "DEBUG Starting loop"
find . -name '*.ecl' -print0 | while read -d $'\0' file
do 
  echo " DEBUG - FILE=$file"
  echo "  DEBUG0 tmpTotalErrors=$tmpTotalErrors --- result=$result"
  function_syntaxCheckFileName "$file" 
  result=$?
  echo "  DEBUG1 tmpTotalErrors=$tmpTotalErrors --- result=$result"
  tmpTotalErrors=$((tmpTotalErrors + result)) 
  echo "  DEBUG2 tmpTotalErrors=$tmpTotalErrors --- result=$result"
done

echo "DEBUG3 tmpTotalErrors=$tmpTotalErrors"
```

It is designed to be run in path **with spaces** so I use this iteration

> find . -name '*.ecl' -print0 | while read -d $'\0' file

The **output** is this:

```
DEBUG Starting loop
 DEBUG - FILE=./a.ecl
  DEBUG0 tmpTotalErrors=0 --- result=0
  DEBUG1 tmpTotalErrors=0 --- result=1
  DEBUG2 tmpTotalErrors=1 --- result=1
 DEBUG - FILE=./b.ecl
  DEBUG0 tmpTotalErrors=1 --- result=1
  DEBUG1 tmpTotalErrors=1 --- result=1
  DEBUG2 tmpTotalErrors=2 --- result=1
DEBUG3 tmpTotalErrors=0
```

My **problem** is that tmpTotalErrors lose its value. It was supposed to be 2 and it is 0.

So my **questions** are:

1. How can I my script work?
2. Why is failing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rewrite the loop to avoid subshel by using **set +m; shopt -s lastpipe**

```
 #!/bin/bash
set +m 
shopt -s lastpipe
touch a.ecl
touch b.ecl

function_syntaxCheckFileName()
{
  return 1 # 1 syntax error
}

tmpTotalErrors=0
result=0
echo "DEBUG Starting loop"

find . -name '*.ecl' -print0 | while read -d $'\0' file
do 
  echo " DEBUG - FILE=$file"
  echo "  DEBUG0 tmpTotalErrors=$tmpTotalErrors --- result=$result"
  function_syntaxCheckFileName "$file" 
  result=$?
  echo "  DEBUG1 tmpTotalErrors=$tmpTotalErrors --- result=$result"
  tmpTotalErrors=$((tmpTotalErrors + result)) 
  echo "  DEBUG2 tmpTotalErrors=$tmpTotalErrors --- result=$result"
done
echo "DEBUG3 tmpTotalErrors=$tmpTotalErrors"
```

It's failing because changes in [subshell](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/SubShell) don't reflect in the parent shell.

Also see this Bash FAQ entry: [I set variables in a loop that's in a pipeline. Why do they disappear after the loop terminates? Or, why can't I pipe data to read?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024) which discusses a number of alternative solutions.

Comment: I tried your code and it is not entering in the loop. Output is `DEBUG Starting loop
DEBUG3 tmpTotalErrors=0`

Comment: Changed with same result. My line now is `while read -r -d '' file` Could you update your answer?

Comment: @OscarFoley Since your bash support `lastpipe`, can you try to use `set +m;  shopt -s lastpipe` in your script as it is (without rewriting anything else)?

Comment: Never seen that shopt... how can I use it? Thanks a lot for the help btw...

Comment: @OscarFoley See the linked wiki which explains it. You just need to add the two lines I mentioned in my previous comment into your script?

Comment: I managed to get it working :-)  I am going to edit your answer to show correct code...

Comment: @OscarFoley Please feel free to fix it!

Comment: Done. Now the answer will be more easy to follow :-)

Comment: @OscarFoley Great! Thanks :)